# How to keep SVN from updating a directory already in repository

Tags: svn, ignore

This isn't, I don't think, a standard svn ignore question.

I have a repository with a huge directory in it that I don't want.  Because others using the repository *do*, I can't just delete it from the tree.  BUT, I don't want to redownload this directory every time I do a svn up.  I can understand that ignore will prevent directories that I have from being uploaded to svn, but how I can I tell svn that I don't want it to redownload particular directories that are already in the repository.

What I do...

```
svn up
rm badDirectory
```

and then future svn up's redownload it.  I want to prevent that.

Thanks!

edit:  OK.  I was hoping that SVN had a built in option that I just hadn't noticed yet.  I was hoping to avoid having to "hack" around subversion's inadequacies, but the options below seem like acceptable alternatives.

edit again to address a couple of comments:

> Is there particular reason why you
>   cannot check-out that folder and keep
>   it ? no disk space (probably not since
>   you can check-out it) ? security
>   reason ?

I could check out the folder. The entire svn repository is about 291 megs..  290 of it is in this "bad" directory.  Basically, some other people who have control over the repository (and therefore get to decide what goes in there) put a directory in there that really didn't need to be in there.  I didn't mean for this to be a question about policy and the "proper & right" ways to use svn.  I was just wondering if there was a technical solution.

> Can you give a better description of
>   the tree structure of the repository?
>   Are there files at the same level as
>   the bad directory, or only other
>   directories? –

Basic structure:

```
repository root
 - good dir 1
    - plenty of subdirs in all of these directories
 - good dir 2
 - good dir X
 - bad dir 1
 - bad dir 2
 - bad dir X 
 - good file 1
 - good file 2
 - good file X
```

Comment: Is there particular reason why you cannot check-out that folder and keep it ? no disk space (probably not since you can check-out it) ? security reason ?

Comment: Can you give a better description of the tree structure of the repository?  Are there files at the same level as the bad directory, or only other directories?

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question but, are you able to change your versioning system? Git, for example would let you chekout the project, make a local branch for youself, and remove that offending folder from it. Future updates from that branch would not touch what you deleted locally.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So I just came up with what I think is about the fastest answer to the question.  Since SVN doesn't have a way to autoignore directories that I don't want updated...

Here's my existing dir structure:

root
 -> goodDir 1
 -> goodDir 2
  etc

I've deleted the bad directories from my checkout.  I can't do an 'svn up' from the root directory, because it tries to recheck out the bad directories.

But, the following command works nicely:

```
  ls | xargs svn up
```

Short, sweet, simple, and easy to remember.

Comment: That won't pull new files into the current directory will it? 

If someone adds a new file/folder to the top level directory, you'll miss out.

Comment: Also, I think "svn up *" has the same effect.

Comment: If you use a script like that to commit, your changes will be spread over several revisions rather than one. The solution using sparse checkouts is better.

Answer (score 18):

I went with the sparse checkout route similar to what Stefan mentioned. The difference is I excluded a whole directory.

Here's what I did to exclude a whole directory and all its subdirectories. Note: the unwanted directory was already on my disk so I deleted it first.

`$ rm -rf unwanted-directory

$ svn checkout url/to/repo/unwanted-directory unwanted-directory --depth empty

$ cd root/of/my/tree

$ svn update` <- unwanted-directory is not acquired from the repository

For reference, we have a 'prototype' directory in our tree with a bunch of experimental code. Since I don't work in this area, I have no interest in having the 1G to sources in my multiple development trees.

Comment: Great. For reference, to do the same with TortoiseSVN in Windows: (1) right-click the unwanted directory in the local copy, select TortoiseSVN > Update to revision... (2) Set Update Depth to Exclude. (3) Click OK. The unwanted directory disappears from the local copy and does not re-appear.

Answer (score 10):

You can do a [sparse checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html):

```
svn co url/to/repo mywc --depth=files
```

that will get you a wc with only the files in it, no subfolders.
You can now get all the folders you want with

```
svn up url/to/repo/subfolder1 --set-depth infinity 
svn up url/to/repo/subfolder2 --set-depth infinity 
svn up url/to/repo/subfolder3 --set-depth infinity 
...
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I wanted. Plus it can be done from Tortoise SVN with an “Update to Revision” on the unwanted folders and setting the depth to “only this item” or “exclude”.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a script to svn update --non-recursive the current directory, then individually update the remaining subdirectories recurvively. With a bash script you could loop over all the subdirectories and just skip over the offending one.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

BADDIR="bad"
FILELIST="*"

svn update --non-recursive

for file in $FILELIST
do
if [ -d $file ]
then
   if [ $file != $BADDIR ] 
   then
     svn update $file
   fi
fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

If you rename the .svn directory in the bad folder and then run an update, svn will skip over the directory and say it was deleted even though it's still there.

You will need to put it back though when you want to commit, at least at an upper level which contains the bad directory.

Answer (score 1):

Update all current location data except some bad directory :

```
svn up `svn ls | grep -v badDirectory`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could specify --non-recursive or -N to suppress it from getting all the subdirs

and the explicitly do an update on the ones that you want.

A small batch file would make it easily repeatble

\0

Answer (score 0):

Solutions already provided, I'd say that the need to ignore one part of the repository on a regular basis is a clear sign of bad repository structure. Try to find a way to move it to a different location inside repository or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Kirby's solution is clean except that it doesn't update the current directory.

If you have a structure like this:

```
root -
     |-subdir1
     |-subdir2
     |-fileA
     |-fileB
```

Kirby's solution won't update fileA, fileB and any other files that are later added to the root dir.

You'll want to add a "svn up -N". You could do this with an alias and a semicolon:

```
alias myup='ls | args svn up; svn up -N'
```

(That's bash alias syntax. If you're using a different shell, alter as needed)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command

```
find -maxdepth 1 ! -name . ! -name .svn ! -name badDirectory -exec svn up {} \;
```

Keep appending all the directories before -exec like ! -name directoryname

```
find -maxdepth 1 ! -name . ! -name .svn ! -name badDirectory ! -name badDirectory2 ! -name badDirectory3 -exec svn up {} \;
```

Comment: As Stephen Pape mentioned, even this method won't pull new files from the current directory. But it just saves you without the need for deleting the badDirectory.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst considering vendor-specific solution, in TortoiseSVN you can achieve it by following the procedures described on the [manual page](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html), after the listing inside the section "Checkout Depth".

> If you check out a sparse working copy (i.e., by choosing something other than fully recursive for the checkout depth), you can fetch additional sub-folders later by using the repository browser (the section called “The Repository Browser”) or the check for modifications dialog (the section called “Local and Remote Status”).
>
> In windows explorer, Right click on the checked out folder, then use TortoiseSVN → Repo-Browser to bring up the repository browser. Find the sub-folder you would like to add to your working copy, then use Context Menu → Update item to revision....

**BUT:** I'd like to add that I'd change the final step. Instead of finding the sub-folder you'd like to add (or remove) from the working copy, right click on the root folder, choose "Update item to revision...", on Working Depth click on button "Choose Items" and select all the childs on the file manager that opens.

Answer (score 0):

I see the question was asked quite some time back, but if you are still interested, I stumbled upon a nice blog that explains different ways of using "svn:ignore"

Here is the link : http://superchlorine.com/2013/08/getting-svn-to-ignore-files-and-directories/

As explained in the blog, you could probably create a list of "bad folders" in a file and use "svn propset svn:ignore -R-F bad_folder_list_file"

Hope that helps !

Answer (score -1):

If it's not a necessary folder for day to day work for you (or your group) you could ask the administrator to update the svn hierarchy to move that folder at the same level (or higher) than the folders you have to update.

for example

```
projet - non-essential folder 
       \ essential folder
```

and you will only have to update (check-out) the "essential folder" and the others will also
have to update (check-out) the "non-essential folder".