# How to prevent svn updates on specific file(s)/folder(s)?

Tags: svn, project

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to keep SVN from updating a directory already in repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508135/how-to-keep-svn-from-updating-a-directory-already-in-repository)

everybody!

I need your help! I svn up'ped project on server and have this structure:

```
$ ls -a
.  ..  api  common  srv  static  .svn  web
```

How to prevent srv folder from svn updates?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove `srv` folder. Then update it with `--depth=empty` option. After this, `srv` folder will always be empty on every `svn up` of whole project.

```
svn up --depth=empty srv
```

Comment: That's what I want! ^_^ Thanks!

Comment: Didn't work.  Removed my directory, then updated with --depth=empty, then updated directory, it began restoring all the files.